# Flip SVG vertically using an unusual viewbox

Tags: svg

I'm trying to flip a SVG vertically while using a viewbox like `1000 1000 50 50`. In general, I know how to do it, but I'm somehow confused by the way coordinate systems are treated in SVG. Please find my test snippets below.

Example 4 contains what I'm tying to achieve, but which does not work. Any idea?

**Example 1: Basic SVG (works)**

```html
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 50 50" style="background-color: red">
    <g>
        <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="20" y2="20" stroke-width="2" stroke="black" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

**Example 2: Flipped Basic SVG (works)**

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 50 50" style="background-color: red">
    <g transform="translate(0,50) scale(1,-1)">
    <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="20" y2="20" stroke-width="2" stroke="black" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

**Example 3: Basic SVG, with unusual viewbox (works)**

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="200" height="200" viewBox="1000 1000 50 50" style="background-color: red">
    <g>
    <line x1="1000" y1="1000" x2="1020" y2="1020" stroke-width="2" stroke="black" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

**Example 4: Basic SVG, with unusual viewbox, flipped (does not work)**

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="200" height="200" viewBox="1000 1000 50 50" style="background-color: red">
    <g transform="translate(0,1000) scale(1,-1)">
    <line x1="1000" y1="1000" x2="1020" y2="1020" stroke-width="2" stroke="black" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transform commands are right-multiplied; wich means in your fourth example the line is first scaled (y=1000 moves to y=-1000) and afterwards translated (y=-1000 moves to y=0). Its final position in userspace coordinates is

```
<line x1="1000" y1="0" x2="1020" y2="-20" stroke-width="2" stroke="black" />
```

Your viewBox covers y-coordinates between 1000 and 1050; the line is far away from that.

If your goal is to maintain the same viewBox, the right transform is

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="200" height="200" viewBox="1000 1000 50 50" style="background-color: red">
    <g transform="translate(0,2050) scale(1,-1)">
    <line x1="1000" y1="1000" x2="1020" y2="1020" stroke-width="2" stroke="black" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

The formula is: (2 * the distance from the upper corner to origin + height of the viewBox)